# Rails serialization converts 0 to String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I've got a model that uses the default Rails serialization to serialize an array. Behold:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :number_of_free_jobs
end
```

`number_of_free_jobs` is an array of FixNums, but for some reason Rails is converting all the entries that are 0 into strings, but leaving the rest as FixNums, check it:

```
account = Account.last
account.number_of_free_jobs = [10, 5, 0, 1]
account.save
account.number_of_free_jobs 
=> [10, 5, "0", 1]
```

Converting the 0 to a String means some comparisons are failing. I can just map the array with `to_i` but I'm curious as to why this is happening. I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Can you execute the following code in your rails console? Sorry, this should be a comment but without styling it would be confusing. a = [10,5,0,1] b = a.to_yaml c = YAML.load(b) What do you get?

Comment: This resulted in the same problem. I found the issue though, check out my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the [Tolk](https://github.com/tolk/tolk) gem installing [safe_yaml](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml/) as a dependency. Removing Tolk removed the dependency and zeroes are no longer being converted to strings. Bit of a strange one, I'll look into why safe_yaml does this...

Comment: Monkey-Patching side effects! you should report this behaviour/bug at safe_yaml's [issue tracker](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml/issues)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't occur on my machine(Sqlite3, Rails 3.2.13 & Ruby 1.9.3):

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> Account
=> Account(id: integer, number_of_free_jobs: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
irb(main):002:0> Account.create
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (9.5ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("created_at", "number_of_free_jobs", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 20 May 2013 18:19:26 UTC +00:00], ["number_of_free_jobs", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 20 May 2013 18:19:26 UTC +00:00]]
   (179.1ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Account id: 2, number_of_free_jobs: nil, created_at: "2013-05-20 18:19:26", updated_at: "2013-05-20 18:19:26">
irb(main):003:0> account = Account.last
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" ORDER BY "accounts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Account id: 2, number_of_free_jobs: nil, created_at: "2013-05-20 18:19:26", updated_at: "2013-05-20 18:19:26">
irb(main):004:0> account.number_of_free_jobs = [10, 5, 0, 1]
=> [10, 5, 0, 1]
irb(main):005:0> account.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "number_of_free_jobs" = '---
- 10
- 5
- 0
- 1
', "updated_at" = '2013-05-20 18:19:46.430558' WHERE "accounts"."id" = 2
   (155.9ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):006:0> account.number_of_free_jobs 
=> [10, 5, 0, 1]
```

Can you provide steps to reproduce this issue? perhaps a sample app on github which has this error/bug/behaviour?